# Customize percentages displayed in report.html by locust

Tags: performance, testing, report, locust

I'm trying to add 98% in the locust report. The percentage is calculated by the application, in appears in the terminal. I just want it to appear in the html report next to the others. Any ideas on how to do that? [report.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEFPq.jpg)

I tried using PERCENTILES_TO_REPORT, but this option actually calculates custom percentiles. 98% is already calculated, it just needs to show up in the report.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like support for customizing percentiles was recently added to Locust.

https://github.com/locustio/locust/pull/2313

I haven't tried it, but based on the committed tests it seems you'd use it like this:

```
from locust.stats import PERCENTILES_TO_CHART

PERCENTILES_TO_CHART[0] = 0.9
PERCENTILES_TO_CHART[1] = 0.4
```